# Oneplus 3T Chrome/Downloads app on Android - "Can't open file"

Tags: chrome-for-android, downloading, system-error

When I download a doc or docx file via Chrome, it often happens that I can't open it directly. Where with, say, a pdf, the file will open in e.g. Acrobat straight after i tap 'download', doing the same with a doc/docx just brings up a notification on the lower half of the screen. Tapping this opens the system download manager. If I tap on the file, I see the dialogue "Can't open file" appear.

Opening the file through file manager works fine.

Also, downloading the file via Firefox shows the expected behaviour of opening the docx file straight away in MS Word/Google Docs/Libreoffice Viewer.

Should this be understood as a Chrome issue or a Downloads app issue? Either way, I need an urgent solution to this for work reasons. This is not just an inconvenience for me - i work for agencies where several ppl are offered the same job, so if I am slowed down by just a few seconds, I can miss out on a job.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue on Android 6.0.1 with a Nexus 5. It also occurred with various viewers.

I solved it by going to:
Settings->Apps >Microsoft Word>Open by default and then selecting the box clear defaults.

Potentially you should repeat this for the other viewers.